# Dynamically alias columns from a view query SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I use dynamic SQL to query a table, and then use one of the results to alias a column?

I'm trying something like:

```
SELECT 
  ID, ModelName INTO #tmpTable  
FROM Models
```

And then:

```
SELECT 
  ModelNumber AS (SELECT ModelName FROM #tmpTable)  
FROM NewModels
```

For those asking for more detail:
We have a view that contains everything we want, but the columns are IDs like "def123". In another table we have the names that resolve the IDs like "def123", "FName". We want to query the view but have the name appear (using AS) instead of the ID. Essentially, we want to query the definitions table in the AS statement to get dynamic naming.

Comment: Can you give some sample data for us to work with please?

Comment: looks like you could do this off a simple join - whats the relationship between models and new models?

Comment: Unless #tmpTable only ever contains one unique value, I don't understand what you're looking for. Don't dumb down your problem, it makes it harder to solve, not easier.

Comment: A column can only have one name. So if you want a different name for each model as the column's name, that will not work. You can however build a string like `'SELECT ModelNumber AS [<what ever you like, insert here>] FROM NewModels'` and have it executed by [`EXECUTE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [`sp_executesql`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). But what's the point? You could have done that without dynamic SQL too.

Comment: See update of the post for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to bend the dynamic SQL, only realize the truth of it, there is no need for it...

A ModelName by another other ModelNumber will still smell the same ...

`#IMissSQLQuotes`

```
select ID
     , ModelName as ModelNumber
  from NewModels
```

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. I want to _dynamically_ change the value after the as, based on another queries' results.

Comment: As it is written this solves your issue, using my magic 8 ball I'm going to guess, that you want the data from one column to be the column name for a corresponding column of data. I will reference you to @larnu and the 4 up-voted comment. Please add a table definition and some sample data. Off the cuff it seems as though you'll be looking to use a pivot statement in addition to your dynamic SQL. Adding sample data and an illustration a lot of data ppl can figure out what you're looking for. When I have customers asking for this I typically show them other options as a result set.

Answer (score 0):

One possible path to consider would be to replace alias names in a dynamic sql.
Based on a table with the new alias names.

Example snippet:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#NewModels') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #NewModels;
CREATE TABLE #NewModels (ModelNumber int, ModelType char(1));
INSERT INTO #NewModels (ModelNumber, ModelType) values 
(100, 'A'),
(101, 'B'),
(102, 'C');

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpModelNames') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpModelNames;
CREATE TABLE #tmpModelNames (Code varchar(30) primary key, ModelName varchar(30));
INSERT INTO #tmpModelNames (Code, ModelName) values 
('Col1', 'Model Name 1'), 
('Col2', 'Model Name 2');

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(max) = 'SELECT 
  ModelNumber AS [Col1], 
  ModelType AS [Col2]
FROM #NewModels
WHERE ModelNumber = @ModelNumber';

select @Sql = replace(@Sql, quotename(Code), quotename(ModelName)) from #tmpModelNames;
--select @Sql as Sql;

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql, N'@ModelNumber int', @ModelNumber = 101;
```

Returns:

```
Model Name 1  Model Name 2
------------  -------------
101           B
```